How to move focus back to the restored position in Android TV by Compose?
I use a LazyColumn which contains several LazyRow.
When the focus moves to another row, for example, from row A to row B, I need to restore the last focused position in row A; And when the focus is back to row A, I need to move the focus to the restored position. How can I make it?
In default situation, for example, the focus is in the 3rd position in row B, and when I click the Up button to move the focus back to row A, it will move to the 3rd position in row A as well.
In my project, the lazyRow contains several AppCard, which likes:
@Composable
fun AppCard(
    app: App,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: (App) -> Unit = {}
) {
    Card(
        onClick = { onClick(app) },
        modifier = modifier
            .widthIn(max = 120.dp)
            .aspectRatio(16f / 9f)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            AsyncImage(
                model = app.appIcon,
                contentDescription = app.appName
            )
        }
    }
}

And I try to init a FocusRequester in every AppCard's modifier, but I found it hard to know if the focus has leaved the row. And for each row I need to store the last focus position.
class CatalogViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _categoriesMap = MutableStateFlow<Map<String, List<App>>>(emptyMap())
    val categoriesMap: StateFlow<Map<String, List<App>>> = _categoriesMap
    ...
}


@Composable
fun CatalogBrowser(viewModel: CatalogViewModel) {
    val categoriesMap by viewModel.categoriesMap.collectAsState(emptyMap())
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 48.dp, vertical = 32.dp)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(categoriesMap.entries.toList()) { categoryIndex, entry ->
            val (category, appList) = entry
            Column {
                Text(text = category, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 12.dp))
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(6.dp))

                LazyRow(
                    modifier = Modifier.height(67.5.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 10.dp),
                ) {
                    itemsIndexed(appList) { appIndex, app ->
                        val cardRequester = remember {
                            FocusRequester()
                        }
                        AppCard(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .focusRequester(cardRequester)
                                .padding(vertical = 6.dp),
                            app = app,
                            onClick = { onCardSelected(app) }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Now I found how to fix it. Just simply add focusRestorer to modifier can fix it like:
Box(modifier = Modifier.focusRestorer()) {...}

We can also add a focusRequester to focusRestorer, in case of using our own focus logic.
